# Sort php array and keep the smaller of time duplicated elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, duplicates

I have the following array $data in php.

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:00:00
                [value] => 0.0107
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:05:35
                [value] => 0.0321
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:05:35
                [value] => 0.0107
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:06:41
                [value] => 0.0535
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:06:41
                [value] => 0.0107
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [time] => 2014-12-01T00:13:04
                [value] => 0.0321
            )
)
```

I sort the data of array, grouging them by date, using the following code:

```
$sortedData = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($element['time']);
   $date = date("d.m.Y", $timestamp); 
    if ( ! isSet($sortedData[$date]) ) { 
        $sortedData[$date] = array($element);
    } else { 
        $sortedData[$date][] = $element;
    }
}
```

So the result is of the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [01.12.2014] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:00:00
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:05:35
                    [value] => 0.0321
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:05:35
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:06:41
                    [value] => 0.0535
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:06:41
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )
...
)
```

The problem is that the array includes elements with the same time but different value. Is there a way to filter the duplicates (time duplicated elements) in order to keep only the smaller (value) element of duplicates?

So I would like something like this (the index of each element is the time and the value is the smaller of the duplicated elements of previous array):

```
Array
(
    [01.12.2014] => Array
        (
            [2014-12-01T00:00:00] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:00:00
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )

            [2014-12-01T00:05:35] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:05:35
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )

            [2014-12-01T00:06:41] => Array
                (
                    [time] => 2014-12-01T00:06:41
                    [value] => 0.0107
                )
...
)
```

Any help how to do that? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You've already done one level of grouping, you just need to apply virtually the same technique again to group by time instead of date and replace instead of append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work fine mate:

```
$sortedData = array();
        foreach ($data as $element) {
            $timestamp = strtotime($element['time']);
            $date = date("d.m.Y", $timestamp); 
            if ( ! isset($sortedData[$date][$element['time']]) ) { 
                $sortedData[$date][$element['time']] = $element;
$sortedData[$date][$element['time']]['lowest_value'] = $element['value'];
            }
                if ($sortedData[$date][$element['time']]['lowest_value'] >  $element['value']) {
                    $sortedData[$date][$element['time']] = $element;
                    $sortedData[$date][$element['time']]['lowest_value'] =  $element['value'];
                }
        }
```

Here if you want to test:
http://ideone.com/9W5lbZ

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sortedDataHash = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($element['time']);
    if (!isset($sortedDataHash[$timestamp])) {
        $sortedDataHash[$timestamp] = $element;
    } else {
        $sortedDataHash[$timestamp] = $element['value'] < $sortedDataHash[$timestamp]['value']
            ? $element : $sortedDataHash[$timestamp];
    }
}

$sortedData = array();
foreach ($sortedDataHash as $key => $val) {
    $date = date("d.m.Y", $key); 
    if ( ! isSet($sortedData[$date]) ) { 
        $sortedData[$date] = array($val);
    } else { 
        $sortedData[$date][] = $val;
    }
}
```

May be there exits better method ^-^!